# no-return-assign when mapping over object values

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I am trying to create an object whose keys and values are the keys of a different object. However I am getting a linting error:

> ESLint: Arrow function should not return assignment.(no-return-assign)

[image]

```
const obj = {
  a: 1, b: 2, c: 3,
};
const options: {[key: string]: string} = {};
Object.keys(obj).map(i => options[i] = i);
```

Comment: It's complaing about how you are trying to return the assignment of `options[i] = i` in your arrow function. You can use the comma operator for something like this `.map(i => (options[i] = i, options[i]));`. However, in this case, you're not saving the return of `.map()`, and so `.forEach(i => {...})` seems more suitable instead of `.map()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JS 101.
When you use an arrow function without brackets, you should always put a returned value on the right side. If you want to run `options[i] = i`, you should put brackets around it and use `forEach` instead of `map`. `map` returns another array that contains all the returned values from the provided function inside.

Fix it as follows.

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach((i) => {
  options[i] = i;
});
```

However, since you say you want to create an object with keys and values from the values and keys of another object, you may use the following codes.

```
options = Object.keys(obj).reduce((prev, current) => {
  return {
    ...prev,
    current: obj[current],
  };
}, {});
```